# How do I use Stash Get in exp:channel:entries?

Tags: stash

I've got this code on a single entry template - it grabs the entry_id of the entry each time the template is loaded.

```
{exp:stash:set scope="user" save="yes" name="recently-viewed" replace="yes" parse_tags="yes"}{exp:stash:get name name="recently-viewed" scope="user"}{entry_id}|{/exp:stash:set}
```

In a another template I'm trying to use exp:channel:entries like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{exp:stash:get name='recently-viewed'}"}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I'm doing something wrong because no entries are being output by exp:channel:entries. If I use {exp:stash:get name="recently-viewed"} outside exp:channel:entries, I'm getting the expected output, e.g. 2883|7365|3837.

I've tried all day to figure it out - can anyone pleaseee point me in the right direction?

Best wishes
Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with exp:stash:parse

```
{exp:stash:parse}
  {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{stash:recently-viewed}"}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

You may need to add process="end" to the exp:stash:parse tag depending on the order of your templates.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding `parse="inward"` to your channel entries loop so things are parsed in the right order? Would also add a `dynamic="no"` parameter in there for good measure.

```
{exp:channel:entries parse="inward" entry_id="{exp:stash:get name='recently-viewed'}" dynamic="no"}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your entry id is getting parsed before stash. If you turn on output debugging you should see that your entry id is getting output as {exp:stash:get name='recently-viewed'} rather than as the stashed content.

If you look at the New in V2.2.0 section in the Docs the developer explains parsing much better than I could ever. https://github.com/croxton/Stash

Maybe try the stash:embed functionality